# Array values written to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

My code shown below will successfully return an array of values using print_r. How can I can get each value to be inserted into SQL Server "on its own row" in the same column? So far, I have only been able to get the first value in the array to be written to my table. The additional value(s) are not written.
Thx,
_ JT

```
$host = '209.49.180.234';
$hostname = gethostbyaddr( $host );
$rbl  = 'hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com';
$lookup = $hostname . '.' . $rbl;
$value = gethostbynamel($lookup);

    if ($lookup != $value){

       print_r($value);
    }
```

I am unclear where to insert the loop. Like this?:

```
$host = '209.49.180.234';
$hostname = gethostbyaddr( $host );
$rbl  = 'hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com';
$lookup = $hostname . '.' . $rbl;
$value = gethostbynamel($lookup);
   if ($lookup != $value)
    foreach($value as $val) {
         mssql_query("INSERT INTO $table5 (Whitelist_code) VALUES ('".$val."')");
     }

mssql_close($conn);
```

I got it to work. Thanks guys!
_ JT

Comment: loop through the array with foreach()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
  foreach($value as $val) {
    mssql_query("INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES ('".$val."')");
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Sander but I am unclear where to insert the loop. Like this?:$host = '209.49.180.234';
$hostname = gethostbyaddr( $host );
$rbl  = 'hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com';
$lookup = $hostname . '.' . $rbl;
$value = gethostbynamel($lookup);
   if ($lookup != $value)
    foreach($value as $val) {
         mssql_query("INSERT INTO $table5 (Whitelist_code) VALUES ('".$val."')");
     }

mssql_close($conn);

Answer (score 1):

use a foreach loop

```
foreach ($value as $a):
    //access your rows as $a
    //ex.- echo $a; put your sql stuff here instead
endforeach;
```